# How to bind ngSwitch case in div tag in angular?

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel, ng-style

this is the code i'm trying to run:

```
    <div [ngStyle]="getStartTimeStyle()" [ngSwitch]="event?.time">
       Time: {{event?.time}}
    <span *ngSwitchCase="'8:00 am'">(Early start)</span>
    <span *ngSwitchCase="'10:00 am'">(Late Start)</span>
    <span *ngSwitchDefault>(Normal Start)</span>
  </div>
```

but it's showing the error as follows:

error NG8002: Can't bind to 'ngStyle' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.

```
      <div [ngStyle]="getStartTimeStyle()" [ngSwitch]="event?.time">
```

Can't bind to 'ngSwitch' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.

```
    <div [ngStyle]="getStartTimeStyle()" [ngSwitch]="event?.time">
```

Please help, how can I resolve this?

```
                                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import 'CommonModule' in the module where you want to use the 'ngSwitch' and 'ngStyles' directives since both these directives are part of the 'CommonModule'.

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using div use container_element

<container-element [ngSwitch] = "switch_expression">

<some-element * ngSwitchCase = "match_expression_1"> ...

...

<some-element * ngSwitchDefault> ...

I leave you the link of the documentation so that you can look in more detail